# Не получается задеплоить приложение на tomcat в intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, maven, tomcat

Не получается задеплоить свое приложение на tomcat в intellij idea. Использую maven. Подозреваю что дело в артефактах, потому что их не было изначально и я вручную создала один (выбрала тип Web Application: Explored):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот такой получается лог с ошибками и localhost:8080 не открывается:

```
E:\tomee7.0.2\bin\catalina.bat run
C:\jdk1.8\bin\java -Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 -classpath "E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\javaee-api-7.0-1.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\jsp-api.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\servlet-api.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\bval-core-1.1.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\bval-jsr-1.1.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\catalina-ant.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\catalina-ha.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\catalina-storeconfig.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\catalina-tribes.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\catalina.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\commons-cli-1.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\commons-dbcp2-2.1.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\commons-digester-1.8.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\commons-lang-2.6.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\commons-pool2-2.3.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\cxf-core-3.1.8.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.8.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\cxf-rt-management-3.1.8.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\cxf-rt-rs-client-3.1.8.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers-3.1.8.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\cxf-rt-rs-extension-search-3.1.8.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\cxf-rt-rs-json-basic-3.1.8.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\cxf-rt-rs-security-cors-3.1.8.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\cxf-rt-rs-security-jose-3.1.8.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\cxf-rt-rs-security-jose-jaxrs-3.1.8.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\cxf-rt-rs-security-oauth2-3.1.8.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\cxf-rt-rs-service-description-3.1.8.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\cxf-rt-security-3.1.8.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.8.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\ecj-4.5.1.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\el-api.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail-1.9.0-alpha-2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\geronimo-transaction-3.1.3.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\howl-1.0.1-1.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\hsqldb-2.3.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\jasper-el.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\jasper.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\jaspic-api.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\johnzon-core-0.9.5.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\johnzon-jaxrs-0.9.5.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\johnzon-mapper-0.9.5.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\mbean-annotation-api-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\myfaces-api-2.2.11.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\myfaces-impl-2.2.11.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openejb-api-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openejb-client-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openejb-core-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openejb-cxf-rs-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openejb-cxf-transport-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openejb-ejbd-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openejb-hsql-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openejb-http-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openejb-javaagent.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openejb-jee-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openejb-jee-accessors-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openejb-jpa-integration-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openejb-jstl-1.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openejb-loader-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openejb-rest-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openejb-server-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openjpa-2.4.1.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openwebbeans-ee-1.7.0.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openwebbeans-ee-common-1.7.0.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openwebbeans-ejb-1.7.0.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openwebbeans-el22-1.7.0.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openwebbeans-impl-1.7.0.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openwebbeans-jsf-1.7.0.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openwebbeans-spi-1.7.0.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openwebbeans-web-1.7.0.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\quartz-openejb-shade-2.2.1.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\serp-1.14.1.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\slf4j-jdk14-1.7.21.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\stax2-api-3.1.4.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\swizzle-stream-1.6.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\sxc-jaxb-core-0.8.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\sxc-runtime-0.8.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomcat-api.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomcat-coyote.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomcat-dbcp.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomcat-i18n-es.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomcat-i18n-fr.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomcat-i18n-ja.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomcat-jdbc.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomcat-jni.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomcat-util-scan.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomcat-util.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomcat-websocket.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomee-catalina-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomee-common-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomee-jaxrs-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomee-jdbc-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomee-loader-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomee-mojarra-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomee-myfaces-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\tomee-webapp-7.0.2.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\websocket-api.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\xbean-asm5-shaded-4.5.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\xbean-bundleutils-4.5.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\xbean-finder-shaded-4.5.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\xbean-naming-4.5.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\xbean-reflect-4.5.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3\plugins\JavaEE\lib\javaee-impl.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3\lib\openapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3\lib\util.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3\plugins\Tomcat\lib\specifics\tomee-specifics.jar" com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 54972 org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.agent.TomEEAgent
[2016-12-08 05:42:03,134] Artifact dresshop: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Ђ­ов \.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_dresshop_4"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "E:\tomee7.0.2"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "E:\tomee7.0.2\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\jdk1.8\jre"
Using CLASSPATH:       "E:\tomee7.0.2\bin\bootstrap.jar;E:\tomee7.0.2\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.119 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server version:        Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/8.5.6 (7.0.2)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.120 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server built:          Oct 6 2016 20:15:31 UTC
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.120 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server number:         8.5.6.0
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.120 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke OS Name:               Windows 7
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.120 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke OS Version:            6.1
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.120 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Architecture:          amd64
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.120 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Java Home:             C:\jdk1.8\jre
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.120 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke JVM Version:           1.8.0_91-b15
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.120 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.121 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Анюта\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_dresshop_4
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.121 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke CATALINA_HOME:         E:\tomee7.0.2
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.122 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -javaagent:E:\tomee7.0.2\lib\openejb-javaagent.jar
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.122 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.122 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.122 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.123 INFO [main] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.123 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.123 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Dtomee.serialization.class.whitelist=
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.123 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Dtomee.serialization.class.blacklist=-
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.123 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Dtomee.remote.support=true
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.123 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Dopenejb.system.apps=true
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.123 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.123 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.123 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Анюта\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_dresshop_4\conf\logging.properties
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.123 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.124 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Анюта\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_dresshop_4
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.124 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=E:\tomee7.0.2
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.124 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=E:\tomee7.0.2\temp
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.124 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\jdk1.8\jre\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\jdk1.8\bin;C:\android-sdks\tools;C:\android-sdks\platform-tools;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ant1.9.7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Git\cmd;C:\WebServers\usr\local\php5;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Users\Анюта\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;.
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.426 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.465 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.471 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
08-Dec-2016 17:42:04.474 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.237 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'tomee.remote.support=true'
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.254 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'openejb.jdbc.datasource-creator=org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator'
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.384 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> ********************************************************************************
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.384 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> OpenEJB http://tomee.apache.org/
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.385 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Startup: Thu Dec 08 17:42:05 MSK 2016
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.386 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Copyright 1999-2016 (C) Apache OpenEJB Project, All Rights Reserved.
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.386 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Version: 7.0.2
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.387 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Build date: 20161106
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.387 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Build time: 07:23
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.387 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> ********************************************************************************
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.388 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> openejb.home = E:\tomee7.0.2
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.389 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> openejb.base = C:\Users\Анюта\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_dresshop_4
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.390 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.initializeOWB Created new singletonService org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@17c386de
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.391 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.initializeOWB Succeeded in installing singleton service
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.424 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.init TomEE configuration file is 'C:\Users\Анюта\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_dresshop_4\conf\tomee.xml'
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.558 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Tomcat Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Tomcat Security Service)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.566 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.569 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'openejb.system.apps=true'
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.571 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Default Singleton Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Singleton Container)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.583 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.655 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating SecurityService(id=Tomcat Security Service)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.687 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Container(id=Default Singleton Container)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.711 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Assembling app: openejb
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.829 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'openejb.jndiname.format={deploymentId}{interfaceType.openejbLegacyName}'
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.848 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=openejb/DeployerBusinessRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.849 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/openejb/Deployer!org.apache.openejb.assembler.Deployer) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.850 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/openejb/Deployer) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.851 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=openejb/ConfigurationInfoBusinessRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.859 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/openejb/Deployer!org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.cmd.ConfigurationInfo) --> Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.864 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=MEJB) --> Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.864 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=global/openejb/openejb/openejb/Deployer!javax.management.j2ee.ManagementHome) --> Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.876 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Created Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Singleton Container)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.885 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Created Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Singleton Container)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.886 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Created Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Singleton Container)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.887 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=MEJB, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Singleton Container)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.887 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/ConfigurationInfo, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Singleton Container)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.887 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.startEjbs Started Ejb(deployment-id=openejb/Deployer, ejb-name=openejb/Deployer, container=Default Singleton Container)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.893 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.deployMBean Deployed MBean(openejb.user.mbeans:application=openejb,group=org.apache.openejb.assembler.monitoring,name=JMXDeployer)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:05.895 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Deployed Application(path=openejb)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:06.026 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager.initServer Creating ServerService(id=cxf-rs)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:06.334 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start   ** Bound Services **
08-Dec-2016 17:42:06.334 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.printRow   NAME                 IP              PORT  
08-Dec-2016 17:42:06.334 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start -------
08-Dec-2016 17:42:06.334 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start Ready!
08-Dec-2016 17:42:06.334 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Initialization processed in 2855 ms
08-Dec-2016 17:42:06.361 INFO [main] org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBNamingContextListener.bindResource Importing a Tomcat Resource with id 'UserDatabase' of type 'org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase'.
08-Dec-2016 17:42:06.362 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Resource(id=UserDatabase)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:06.366 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting service Catalina
08-Dec-2016 17:42:06.366 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/8.5.6 (7.0.2)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:06.458 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Unable to set the web application class loader property [clearReferencesRmiTargets] to [true] as the property does not exist.
08-Dec-2016 17:42:06.478 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
08-Dec-2016 17:42:06.488 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
08-Dec-2016 17:42:06.491 INFO [main] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server startup in 156 ms
дек 08, 2016 5:42:06 PM org.apache.openejb.client.EventLogger log
INFO: RemoteInitialContextCreated{providerUri=http://localhost:8080/tomee/ejb}
Connected to server
[2016-12-08 05:42:07,440] Artifact dresshop: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
08-Dec-2016 17:42:08.068 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException: Could not resolve (C:\java\dreshop\out\artifacts\dresshop)
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve (C:\java\dreshop\out\artifacts\dresshop)
    at org.apache.openejb.loader.provisining.ProvisioningResolver.doResolve(ProvisioningResolver.java:157)
    at org.apache.openejb.loader.provisining.ProvisioningResolver.realLocation(ProvisioningResolver.java:126)
    at org.apache.openejb.loader.ProvisioningUtil.realLocation(ProvisioningUtil.java:158)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.DeployerEjb.deploy(DeployerEjb.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.security.internal.InternalSecurityInterceptor.invoke(InternalSecurityInterceptor.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:181)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer._invoke(SingletonContainer.java:256)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer.invoke(SingletonContainer.java:212)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.doEjbObject_BUSINESS_METHOD(EjbRequestHandler.java:371)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.processRequest(EjbRequestHandler.java:182)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.processEjbRequest(EjbDaemon.java:360)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.service(EjbDaemon.java:247)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:104)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[2016-12-08 05:42:08,107] Artifact dresshop: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2016-12-08 05:42:08,107] Artifact dresshop: javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve (C:\java\dreshop\out\artifacts\dresshop)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:16.487 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deploying web application directory E:\tomee7.0.2\webapps\manager
08-Dec-2016 17:42:16.493 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.init ------------------------- localhost -> /manager
08-Dec-2016 17:42:16.756 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication Configuring enterprise application: E:\tomee7.0.2\webapps\manager
08-Dec-2016 17:42:16.812 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build Enterprise application "E:\tomee7.0.2\webapps\manager" loaded.
08-Dec-2016 17:42:16.813 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Assembling app: E:\tomee7.0.2\webapps\manager
08-Dec-2016 17:42:16.897 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWebApps using context file E:\tomee7.0.2\webapps\manager\META-INF\context.xml
08-Dec-2016 17:42:16.897 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Deployed Application(path=E:\tomee7.0.2\webapps\manager)
08-Dec-2016 17:42:17.179 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deployment of web application directory E:\tomee7.0.2\webapps\manager has finished in 691 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Наконец нашла ответ. Надо открыть меню  maven projects если его нет, это View->Tool Windows->Maven Projects. В открывшемся меню надо выполнить clean и install. И тогда артефакты создадутся!

Comment: Если они не создались и в этом случае надо проверить чтобы в pox.xml было  <packaging>war</packaging> и после этого сделать clean/install